# Claims and policy based Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, policy, asp.net-authorization

I am using policy-based authorization.
here I'm storing claims information if after login in MVC controller

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = null;
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user[0].Type)
                });
```

here is the Authorization setup in startup.cs configurationServices method

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("OwnerOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role,"Owner"));
            options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
            options.AddPolicy("UserOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));

        });
```

and the controller

```
[Authorize(Policy = "OwnerOnly")]
    public IActionResult NewDepartment()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This authorization redirects to me to (This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 401) page although admin logs in with role. What are the problems here?

Comment: Typically the 401 (although named unauthorized) means you're not authenticated. Are you sure the calling user is logged in?

Comment: yes its logged in, I can get the role of the user

Comment: Can you show how you've tested and determined that?

Comment: I set a breakpoint at ClaimsIdentity and logged in then I noticed that the value of the claim is (Admin) which is the role of the logged in user

Comment: 1. How do you login withe the claims? Use HttpContext or any other way? Pls share with us. 2.  What is your version of asp.net core? 3. If you use version after asp.net core 3.x, be sure `UseRouting`, `UseAuthentication`, and `UseAuthorization` must be called in the order shown in the preceding code.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Startup.cs` you should call, `app.UseAuthorization();`

Comment: I did already but still not working

Answer (score 1):

well, you don't need to define a policy for each roles in your app. you can define your policy like this below:

```
services.AddAuthentication(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(x =>
                {
                    x.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                    x.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                });
            services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
```

and you can control it as `[Authorize(Roles="Owner")]` in top of your action.

that `[Authorize(Roles="Owner")]` Roles comes from your claims that you are setting it in login action.

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = null;
identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
{
  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Owner")
});
```